# Spring Boot with New Relic without modifying dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, newrelic, javaagents

I am trying to configure New Relic to monitor Spring applications created using Spring Boot.  The applications are already in a released state and I would like to be able to integrate New Relic without modifying the dependencies of the java applications, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901959/new-relic-for-spring-boot).

Is there any way to include the new relic agent in such a way that restarting the Spring Boot application with new command line arguments will suffice?

**EDIT**

I had read warnings about using the -javaagent:/path/to/newrelic.jar flag and getting error messages, but had not tried it for myself.  It appears that this option works now.

**SECOND EDIT**

The single spring boot app is reporting two separate applications, one for the Embedded Tomcat server and another for the Java application itself.  Would there be a way to resolve this?

**THIRD EDIT** (for anyone reading this in the future)

My spring boot app was reporting two applications to the New Replic APM tool.  In order to avoid this, I now start the java application with an environment variable:

```
export NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME="my spring boot app"
java -jar spring-boot-app-1.0.jar -javaagent:/path/to/newrelic.jar
```

Comment: Can you add the new relic agent to the JVM lib folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the instructions for standalone applications works as well for spring boot apps:

`java -jar spring-boot-app-1.0.jar -javaagent:/path/to/newrelic.jar`

Comment: could you elaborate on the /path/to/newrelic.jar

I've added it to a folder at the root of my application. But I don't know how to reference it in the javaagent variable.

Is it -javaagent:./newrelic/newrelic.jar?